# How to see followers profile on Google+

Tags: google-plus

I'm a new Google+ account user.  My account displays 15 followers yet when I go to 'People' it only reflects 14 
profiles.  How can I find out (SEE) who the 15th profile belongs to?

Comment: Your numbers don't make sense. If you have 15 followers and can see 15 profiles, there aren't any missing.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I can only see 14 followers.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options.

Either someone unfollowed you and the count on your profile is stale and hasn't been updated yet.

Or the other account has changed their privacy settings so the people in their circles are private. This conversely also covers the other direction of seeing them as followers of a profile.

[image: Who can see the "people in your circles" section on your profile?]

Comment: I don't believe the number is stale.  So, basically, someone can follow me secretly and there is no possible way I can see who it is?  (Thank you). I guess I ask because it means I don't have the option to block them if they are an undesirable follower, correct?

Comment: You can block anyone you want and they can't follow you. In this case you would have to identify them as undesirable via a different method than looking at your followers list.